# Why sidebar TOC lists a section with \paused items many times?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, lists

I'm trying to create my own theme, but as a newbie I have encountered few problems which I wasn't able to solve...

I'm using `\useoutertheme{sidebar}` option and it automaticly creates TOC with sections and subsections, which is as it should be. However, in one section I have

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{itemize}
```

and this shows as a multiple section entries in TOC. Frame number, however, is not affected by `\pause` command and multiple sections.

Any ideas?

---

```
\documentclass[compress,mathserif]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\useoutertheme[width=2cm,height=2cm]{sidebar}
\title[]{Long title}
\author[]{Author}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\section{Lists}
\frametitle{Bullets and lists}
\begin{overprint}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item One 
\item Two 
\item Three 
\end{itemize} 
\end{overprint} 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code snippet is useless since it doesn't allow us to reproduce the problem, Please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the undesired bahaviour.

Comment: Exactly as @GonzaloMedina says: until you post a short full `.tex` file exactly showing your problem, you cannot be helped.

Comment: Here comes the MWE

Comment: @JaniT If you're still interested in the cause of the problem and its solution, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from using `\section` inside a frame with overlay specification (in any case, using `\section` inside a frame doesn't make much sense). All you have to do to solve your problem is to move `\section` outside the `frame` environment:

```
\documentclass[compress,mathserif]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\useoutertheme[width=2cm,height=2cm]{sidebar}
\title[]{Long title}
\author[]{Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Lists}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bullets and lists}
\begin{overprint}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item One 
\item Two 
\item Three 
\end{itemize} 
\end{overprint} 
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Heres the first frame of your example code showing the problem:

[image]

and here's the first frame of my example code, once `\section` was moved outside `frame`:

[image]